# `export PS1='value'` does not propagate to (Korn) subshells for root?

Tags: shell, ksh

Please consider the following /root/.profile:

```
export PS1=value1
export x=value2
```

How come the login shell shows the expected prompt (and $x as value2), while the subshells keep showing $x as value2 but $PS1 as '#'? Just in case, I'm trying this under OpenBSD.

[Yeah, I know... What on earth am I doing with OpenBSD if I don't know this? Just toying... in an isolated, most definitely non-production VM =).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody is interested, somebody finally explained this [in an OpenBSD mailing list](http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=129435482322847&w=2). This behavior is actually expected in OpenBSD, as explained in a comment inside [/usr/src/bin/ksh/main.c](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/ksh/main.c?rev=1.46;content-type=text/plain):

```
safe_prompt = ksheuid ? "$ " : "# ";
{
    struct tbl *vp = global("PS1");

    /* Set PS1 if it isn't set, or we are root and prompt doesn't
     * contain a # or \$ (only in ksh mode).
     */
    if (!(vp->flag & ISSET) ||
        (!ksheuid && !strchr(str_val(vp), '#') &&
        (Flag(FSH) || !strstr(str_val(vp), "\\$"))))
        /* setstr can't fail here */
        setstr(vp, safe_prompt, KSH_RETURN_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your subshells are sourcing something that's resetting PS1.

To debug this, try `ksh -x`. If that doesn't help, you could try running `ksh` in [`strace` or an equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) system call tracing tool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As .profile consists of only these two lines, and there is no .kshrc at all under /root, do you have any ideas as to where or when this sourcing may be taking place?

Comment: @user319845 A added some debugging tips to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following files for rogue PS1 assignments.

```
   /etc/profile
          The  system  wide initialization file, executed for login shells.
   $HOME/.profile
          The personal initialization  file,  executed  for  login  shells
          after /etc/profile.
   $HOME/..kshrc
          Default  personal  initialization file, executed for interactive
          shells when ENV is not set.
   /etc/suid_profile
          Alternative initialization file, executed when instead  of  per-
          sonal  initialization  file  when the real and effective user or
          group id do not match.
```

There may be a typo in that manpage, it probably meant to say: `$HOME/.kshrc`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, /etc/profile, /root/.kshrc and /etc/suid_profile do not exist at all, so no luck there. I never thought PS's would be so enigmatic!